# Cypress intercept - execute same api multiple times with different payload in same test case

Tags: javascript, cypress, cy.intercept

I want to execute the multiple times same API with different payloads, but it's not working.

```
it('call same api with different payload',()=>{
  cy.intercept('PATCH', `**/user/1`,{name:'thava'} ).as("action1")
  cy.intercept('PATCH', `**/user/1`,{name:'prakash'} ).as("action2")

  cy.visit('../app/intercept-identical.html');

  cy.get("#update-action1").click();
  cy.wait(['@action1']);

  cy.get("#update-action2").click();
  cy.wait(['@action2']); // not working
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When requests are identical, only one intercept `routeMatcher` will catch all the calls.

To vary the response, one way is to respond with a function

```js
it('responds to identical requests with different responses', () => {

  let requestNo = 0
  const responses = [ { name: 'thava' }, { name:'prakash' } ]

  cy.intercept('PATCH', '**/user/1', (req) => { 
    req.reply(responses[requestNo++])
  }).as('action');

  cy.visit('../app/intercept-identical.html')

  cy.get("#update-action").click()
  cy.wait('@action')
    .its('response.body.name')
    .should('eq', 'thava')                          // passes

  cy.get("#update-action").click()
  cy.wait('@action')
  .its('response.body.name')
  .should('eq', 'prakash')                          // passes
})
```

Tested with

```html
<body>
  <button id="update-action" onclick="clickhandler()"></button>
  <script>
    function clickhandler() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/user/1', {
        method: 'PATCH'
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

**Note**

`req.reply(res => { res.send(...) }` will ***not stub the request***, it will only modify the response from the live server. If the server targeted is not able to accept 'PATCH', you will get an error.

---

#### Overriding intercepts

If you update to the latest version of Cypress, you can simply over-write the intercept.

The last-added intercept will be the one to catch the request.

```js
it('overrides intercepts', () => {

  cy.visit('../app/intercept-identical.html')

  cy.intercept('PATCH', `**/user/1`, { name:'thava' } ).as("action1")
  cy.get("#update-action").click()
  cy.wait('@action1')
    .its('response.body.name')
    .should('eq', 'thava')                          // passes

  cy.intercept('PATCH', `**/user/1`, { name:'prakash' } ).as("action2")
  cy.get("#update-action").click()
  cy.wait('@action2')
    .its('response.body.name')
    .should('eq', 'prakash')                        // passes
})
```